# get specific character

Tags: java, regex, spring, string, replaceall

I would like to remove Zero from a string, below is an example :

String a : `020200218-0PSS-0010`

```
a.replaceall("-(?:.(?!-))+$", "**REPLACEMENT**")
```

Actual : `020200218-0PSS-0010`
Expected : `020200218-0PSS-10`

I'm using this regex to catch -0010 : `-(?:.(?!-))+$`

I just dont know what to do in the REPLACEMENT section to actually remove the unused zero (not the last zero for exemple "10" and not "1")

Thanks for reading!

Comment: Try: `a.replaceall("-0+(?=[a-9])", "-")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use something like:

```
(?<=-)0+(?=[1-9]\d*$)
```

It translates to "find all zeros which come after a dash, leading up to a non-zero digit, followed by optional digits, till the end of the string."

The demo below is in PHP but it should be valid in Java as well.

https://regex101.com/r/7E2KKQ/1

```
$s.replaceAll("(?<=-)0+(?=[1-9]\d*$)", "")
```

---

This would also work:

```
(?<=-)(?=\d+$)0+
```

> Find a position in which behind me is a dash and ahead of me is nothing but digits till the end of the line. From this position match one or more continuous zeros.

https://regex101.com/r/cdTjOz/1

Comment: Thanks for replying, the probleme with your regex is that it delete all the zero. For example if i have this "010", i want to have this "10" as a result, not this "1"

Comment: @SWah You should add that information to your question and present the multiple formats that may be encountered.

Comment: @SWah What should happen for `000` or `101`?

Comment: I did correct my post thank you ! For 000 i will never happen the last number have to be >0. And for 101 nothing too, there is no unused 0.

Comment: It work perfectly thank you thank you thank you !!! :)

Comment: @SWah You're welcome. I was able to shorten the regex as well if you're interested then see the second example in my post.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```
String result = a.replaceAll("-0+(?=[1-9][0-9]*$)", "-");
```

For the input Sting: `String a = "020200218-0PSS-00000010";`
The output is:
`020200218-0PSS-10`

Comment: It actually worked too thank you, i did aprove the MonkeyZeus one because i think it is actually more simple to do it this way ! But thank you for taking time to find and respond to my answer :)

Answer (score 0):

The pattern `-(?:.(?!-))+$` matches a `-` and 1+ times any char asserting what is directly to the right is not `-`, until the end of the string.

This does not take any digits into account and if successful, will give a full match instead of the zeroes only.

Instead of lookarounds, you might also use a capturing group and use that group in the replacement with a `-` prepended.

```
-0+([1-9]\d*)$
```

**Explanation**

- `-0+` Match `-` and 1 or more times a zero
- `(` Capture **group 1**

  - `[1-9]\d*` Match a digit 1-9 followed by optional digits
- `)` Close group 1
- `$` Assert end of string

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/8ULIKL/1) | [Java demo](https://ideone.com/rBPQka)

As there is only 1 part to replace, you could use [replaceFirst](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceFirst-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-).

```
String a = "020200218-0PSS-0010";
String result = a.replaceFirst("-0+([1-9]\\d*)$", "-$1");
System.out.println(result);
```

Output

```
020200218-0PSS-10
```