# Split String from the last iteration

Tags: java, spring

This post is an update to this one : [get specific character in a string with regex and remove unused zero](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65254409/get-specific-character-in-a-string-with-regex-and-remove-unused-zero)

In the first place, i wanted to remove with an regular expression the unused zero in the last match.

I found that the regular expression is a bit overkill for what i need.

---

Here is what i would like now,

I would like to use `split()` method

to get from this :

```
String myString = "2020-LI50532-3329-00100"
```

this :

```
String data1 = "2020"
String data2 = "LI50532"
String data3 = "3329"
String data4 = "00100"
```

So then i can remove from the LAST `data` the unused Zero

> to convert "00100" in "100"

And then concatenate all the data to get this

```
"2020-LI50532-3329-100"
```

Im not familiar with the split method, if anyone can enlight me about this ^^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Solution using regex:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Test
        System.out.println(parse("2020-LI50532-3329-00100"));
        System.out.println(parse("2020-LI50532-3329-00001"));
        System.out.println(parse("2020-LI50532-03329-00100"));
        System.out.println(parse("2020-LI50532-03329-00001"));
    }

    static String parse(String str) {
        return str.replaceAll("0+(?=[1-9]\\d*$)", "");
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
2020-LI50532-3329-100
2020-LI50532-3329-1
2020-LI50532-03329-100
2020-LI50532-03329-1
```

**Explanation of the regex:**

[One or more](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/quant.html) zeros [followed by](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) a non-zero digit which can be optionally followed by any digit(s) until the end of the string (specified by `$`).

### Solution without using regex:

You can do it also by using `Integer.parseInt` which can parse a string like `00100` into `100`.

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Test
        System.out.println(parse("2020-LI50532-3329-00100"));
        System.out.println(parse("2020-LI50532-3329-00001"));
        System.out.println(parse("2020-LI50532-03329-00100"));
        System.out.println(parse("2020-LI50532-03329-00001"));
    }

    static String parse(String str) {
        String[] parts = str.split("-");

        try {
            parts[parts.length - 1] = String.valueOf(Integer.parseInt(parts[parts.length - 1]));
        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            // Do nothing
        }

        return String.join("-", parts);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
2020-LI50532-3329-100
2020-LI50532-3329-1
2020-LI50532-03329-100
2020-LI50532-03329-1
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. The problem with that is that all the unused zero will be delete, here is what happen : "2020-LI50532-03329-00100" should return "2020-LI50532-03329-100" but with your method it actualy return 2020-LI50532-3329-100" i want to delete ONLY the last unused zero

Comment: @SWah - I thought that you wanted to do it with each part. I've updated the answer to do it only with the last part. Feel free to comment in case of any doubt/issue.

Comment: @SWah - I have also added a pure regex solution. Feel free to comment in case of any doubt/issue.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `substring` method to get rid of the leading zeros...

```
String myString = "2020-LI50532-3329-00100";

String[] data = myString.split("-");
data[3] = data[3].substring(2);

StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
sb.append(data[0] + "-" + data[1] + "-" + data[2] + "-" + data[3]);

String result = sb.toString();

System.out.println(result);
```

Comment: HI, thanks for the reply ! So the problem here is that i wont have always the same string in enter. I give this as an exemple "2020-LI50532-3329-00100". But it can be also this "2020-LI50532-3329-00001", or this "2020-LI50532-3329-100" etc..

Comment: You can always iterate `data[3]` to check the index of the first "valid" number and substring from that index, good luck!

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that we want to remove the leading zeroes of ONLY the last block, maybe we can:

1. Extract the last block
2. Convert it to Integer and back to String to remove leading zeroes
3. Replace the last block with the String obtained in above step

Something like this:

```
public String removeLeadingZeroesFromLastBlock(String text) {
    int indexOfLastDelimiter = text.lastIndexOf('-');
    if (indexOfLastDelimiter >= 0) {
        String lastBlock = text.substring(indexOfLastDelimiter + 1);
        String lastBlockWithoutLeadingZeroes = String.valueOf(Integer.valueOf(lastBlock)); // will throw exception if last block is not an int

        return text.substring(0, indexOfLastDelimiter + 1).concat(lastBlockWithoutLeadingZeroes);
    }

    return text;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(trimLeadingZeroesFromLastPart("2020-LI50532-03329-00100"));
    }

    private static String trimLeadingZeroesFromLastPart(String input) {
        String delem = "-";
        String result = "";
        if (input != null && !input.isEmpty()) {
            String[] data = input.split(delem);
            StringBuilder tempStrBldr = new StringBuilder();
            for (int idx = 0; idx < data.length; idx++) {
                if (idx == data.length - 1) {
                    tempStrBldr.append(trimLeadingZeroes(data[idx]));
                } else {
                    tempStrBldr.append(data[idx]);
                }
                tempStrBldr.append(delem);
            }
            result = tempStrBldr.substring(0, tempStrBldr.length() - 1);
        }
        return result;
    }

    private static String trimLeadingZeroes(String input) {
        int idx;
        for (idx = 0; idx < input.length() - 1; idx++) {
            if (input.charAt(idx) != '0') {
                break;
            }
        }
        return input.substring(idx);
    }

}
```

**Output:**

```
2020-LI50532-3329-100
```

Comment: Hi !thanks for the reply. As i said in an other post, there is the same problem here.I dont want all the unused zero to be delete, here is what happen : "2020-LI50532-03329-00100" should return "2020-LI50532-03329-100" but with your method it actualy return 2020-LI50532-3329-100" i want to delete ONLY the last unused zero

Comment: with my solution if i use String myString = "2020-LI50532-03329-00100", then output is "2020-LI50532-03329-100"

Answer (score 0):

you can convert the last string portion to integer type like below for removing unused zeros:

```
String myString = "2020-LI50532-3329-00100";
String[] data = myString.split("-");
data[3] = data[3].substring(2);
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
sb.append(data[0] + "-" + data[1] + "-" + data[2] + "-" + Integer.parseInt(data[3]));
String result = sb.toString();
System.out.println(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should avoid String manipulation where possible and rely on existing types in the Java language. One such type is the Integer. It looks like your code consists of 4 parts - Year (Integer) - String - Integer - Integer.

So to properly validate it I would use the following code:

```
  Scanner scan = new Scanner("2020-LI50532-3329-00100");

  scan.useDelimiter("-");

  Integer firstPart = scan.nextInt();
  String secondPart = scan.next();
  Integer thirdPart = scan.nextInt();
  Integer fourthPart = scan.nextInt();
```

Or alternatively something like:

```
  String str = "00100";
  int num = Integer.parseInt(str);
  System.out.println(num);
```

If you want to reconstruct your original value, you should probably use a NumberFormat to add the missing 0s.

The main points are:

- Always try to reuse existing code and tools available in your language
- Always try to use available types (LocalDate, Integer, Long)
- Create your own types (classes) and use the expressiveness of the Object Oriented language